# How to switch the iron-router layoutTemplate if not logged in?

Tags: meteor

In iron-router I use this before hook to check if logged in:

```
requireLogin: function(pause) {
    if (! Meteor.user()) {
      if (Meteor.loggingIn())
        this.render(this.loadingTemplate);
      else
        this.render('accessDenied');
      pause();
}
```

The problem is that I want to switch the layoutTemplate if they are not logged in. I'm using a login drop-down by the way. Advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To switch to another layout template, I believe you can do:

```
this.layout('yourLayoutTemplate');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `this.setLayout`, as stated in this discussion: [Redirecting not logged-in users with iron-router... Again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429564/redirecting-not-logged-in-users-with-iron-router-again)