# How can you move between pages in an onBeforeAction for not-logged-in users with Meteor's iron-router?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am using this method of redirecting users who are not logged in to another page:

[Redirecting not logged-in users with iron-router... Again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429564/redirecting-not-logged-in-users-with-iron-router-again)

The code:

```
EXCLUDED = ['signin', 'signup', 'forgotPassword', 'terms']
Router.onBeforeAction must_login, except: EXCLUDED
must_login = (pause) ->
  if Meteor.user()
    @setLayout @lookupLayoutTemplate() or 'blank'
  else
    if localStorage.getItem('has_logged_in_before') or Router.current().path is '/signin'
      @setLayout 'signin'
    else
      @setLayout 'signup'
    pause()
```

For the initial "/" page load, the `signin` or `signup` layout is correctly rendered, depending on the browser's localStorage. However, there is a link on the signup page: `<a href="/signin">`. When it is clicked, the URL changes, but the page stays the same, and onBeforeAction is not rerun. What is the best way to get the page to change?

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but you probably want your link to look something like `<a href="{{pathFor 'signin'}}">` to actually get there via the router instead of requesting a hard reload.

Comment: Hi David, `pathFor 'signin'` just returns `"/signin"`, and either way a new HTTP request / hard reload isn't being made. I've been assuming Iron Router listens to all href clicks and prevents the HTTP request and pushes onto the history api?

Comment: Sorry, please ignore the crazytalk. I didn't get enough sleep last night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the Router.current().path is still "/" when you check it. It will change after the "onBeforeAction" is done, hence, the if else checks put you in signup again. 
Try

```
if localStorage.getItem('has_logged_in_before') or this.route.name is 'signin'
```

if that won't work console.log the Router.current().path to double check my suspicion, and just try to find out how to get the requested URL.

Let me know how the debugging goes!

Comment: Thanks for the info on `route.name`. However, when the `<a href="/signin">` is clicked, the URL changes, but `must_login` is not rerun. The `console.log` I have at the beginning of the function doesn't get called.

Comment: So.. That's good, I believe. Show me how you declare route for /signin then. Or, actually, sounds like you should just get rid of the "signin" and "signup" from your EXCLUDED array.