# Meteor.js redirect to "dedicated" page before email is verified

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have this logic that I'm trying to implement and I'm failing to do so... Here is the deal. I have implemented the confirmation mail for new users and now with the code that I will paste bellow I'm basically blocking the user from login into the app before he confirms he's email address. Okay fairly clear. But now I want to send him to a dedicated "verifiaction" page where it will only be some kind of text like "You need to verify you email before you can login, click to resend the confirmation link, blablabla". Im also using iron router.

Im doing this for the check:

```
//(server-side) called whenever a login is attempted
Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function(attempt){
  if (attempt.user && attempt.user.emails && !attempt.user.emails[0].verified ) {
    console.log('email not verified');

    // Router.go('verification'); - some kind of my "logic" what I want to 


  }
  return true;
});
```

Comment: is the conditional working? If so, what is wrong with `Router.go`? Where is the fail point?

Comment: The following:
1) http://screencast.com/t/ClX78bCo
2) http://screencast.com/t/ClX78bCo
3) http://screencast.com/t/nPjhxAkA3qjb

Comment: It's hitting the console.log, and then trying to create the user to go to the page. Does your router.js require a logged in and verified user to get to any page (or specifically the verification page), and that's why it's failing?

Comment: I'm assuming your using Iron Router... which may or may not be true...

Comment: Yes, I'm using iron router. The default function if I just add "return false" instead of "Router.go" and then I just get the message: failed login atempt. So that is okay as I don't want the user to login before he has confirmed, but instead I want to redirect him on this special page where I explain the situation why can't he login :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [discussion with the same issue here](https://gentlenode.com/journal/meteor-20-verify-an-email-with-meteor-accounts/42) and in the comments, a user suggests resending the verify email token and alerting the user, instead of redirecting to a page, which would be simpler. The code for that would look like:

```
Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function(attempt){
  if (attempt.user && attempt.user.emails && !attempt.user.emails[0].verified ) {
    Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(user._id);
    Alert('Your email has not been verified, we have re-sent the email. Please verify before logging in.');
    //you could also use a modal or something fancy if you want.

}
  return true;
});
```

If definitely want to create a page, there is [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429564/redirecting-not-logged-in-users-with-iron-router-again) about ways to do that, but how you do it it depends on whether you want it to be part of the layout or not.